# Setting a delay between Firecracker microVM tap devices on the same host

Tags: linux, networking, ip, iptables, traffic-shaping

I have set up two microVMs using Firecracker on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS host and have attached a tun/tap device for each of them. Now I'm trying to set a delay between the two VMs (say 100ms) using `tc` so that I get a RTT of 200ms between them, but I can't seem to get it working properly.

Ideally, I would want to specify the two devices directly in `tc` but it seems that I have to specify their networks for it to work.

Here's how the taps are set up (in accordance with the [Firecracker documentation](https://github.com/firecracker-microvm/firecracker/blob/master/docs/network-setup.md)), one for each machine A and B:

```bsh
# create a tap device
sudo ip tuntap add tapA mode tap
sudo ip tuntap add tapB mode tap
# set up tap device ip address
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.29/30 dev tapA
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.33/30 dev tapB
# set up tap device
sudo ip link set tapA up
sudo ip link set tapB up
# enable forwarding
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
# add iptables config
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tapA -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tapB -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

As you can see, I'm giving each machine a tiny dedicated network (`10.0.0.28/30` for A and `10.0.0.32/30` for B) and specifying the IP addresses that the taps will get on the host side. I'm booting the machines with addresses `10.0.0.30/30` for A and `10.0.0.34/30` for B (config set at boot) and I can successfully ping them from each other and from the host.

From my research I have found the `tc` commands that I expect would work:

```bsh
# create a qdisc for tapA
tc qdisc add dev tapA root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev tapA parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10.0Gbit
tc class add dev tapA parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 10.0Gbit ceil 10.0Gbit
# add a delay of 100ms
tc qdisc add dev tapA parent 1:2 handle 2: netem delay 100.0ms
# only apply that delay when the packet comes from A's network and goes to B's network
tc filter add dev tapA protocol ip parent 1: prio 5 u32 match ip dst 10.0.0.32/30 match ip src 10.0.0.28/30 flowid 1:2

# do the same for tapB
tc qdisc add dev tapB root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev tapB parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10.0Gbit
tc class add dev tapB parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 10.0Gbit ceil 10.0Gbit
tc filter qdisc add dev tapB parent 1:2 handle 2: netem delay 100.0ms
# but this time going from B's network to A's network
tc filter add dev tapB protocol ip parent 1: prio 5 u32 match ip dst 10.0.0.28/30 match ip src 10.0.0.32/30 flowid 1:2
```

I would expect this to add a delay on all outgoing packets from A to B and vice versa, but nothing happens. Strangely enough, setting these filters works:

```bsh
# matching destination of A on A's tap
# this should match incoming packets from B to A on tapA
tc filter add dev tapA protocol ip parent 1: prio 5 u32 match ip dst 10.0.0.28/30 match ip src 10.0.0.32/30 flowid 1:2

# and vice versa for tapB
tc filter add dev tapB protocol ip parent 1: prio 5 u32 match ip dst 10.0.0.32/30 match ip src 10.0.0.28/30 flowid 1:2
```

If I understand correctly, this means that `tc` checks incoming packets and applies the correct filter. But that isn't really what I expected to happen, I would prefer outgoing packets to be filtered and delayed. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some further research and I think I'm beginning to understand what is happening here. If anyone is sure on the details, please leave an answer below, but just for anyone who might come across this I'm leaving my explanation here as well.

[overview of packets in a ping command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlHXI.png)

I thought that a tap looks the same to the microVM as well as the host, but I don't think that's quite right. As you can see in the picture (showing the steps of a simple `ping` command), when I send a ping from machine A to machine B, the packet is outgoing from the perspective of A but incoming from the perspective of the host, since the hosts `tapA` device is attached to a `eth0` device in A. Both devices together actually form the `tun/tap`. Hence the packet is also outgoing on `tapB`` and (this makes sense) incoming on B.

Since `tc` can only manage outgoing packets and not incoming ones (at least if you don't redirect them via some other virtual interface), I can only apply the A->B delay on `tapB` (where the packet is outgoing to B) and the B->A delay on `tapA`.

For now I am keeping this workaround until something better comes along.